# jquery not finding image in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, class, attributes, find

**Answered**

I have a piece of jquery code that works in FF but not in IE. Adding to my confusion is that an almost identical piece of code works in both.

I have a `div` with class of imghead and imghead2. Depending on the src of the first `img` tag I want to append a piece of code

**This code works in both browsers:**

```
$(".imghead2 img[src=/img/image.gif]").each(function() {
        $(".imghead2").prepend('<a href="#"><img src="/img/image" border="0" id="anniversary" alt="" /></a>');          
 });
```

**This Code only works in FF**

```
  $(".imghead img[src=/img/mh_image.jpg]").each(function() {
        $(".imghead").prepend('<a href="#"><img src="/img/image.png" border="0" id="anniversary" alt="" /></a>');
         });
```

As far as I can see these snippets are identical - I actually just pasted the working one and changed the `imghead2` to `imghead`. In addition if I remove the `$(".imghead img[src=/img/mh_image.jpg]").each(function() {` It prepends properly.

Edit:
Here is the html:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="imghead2" style="float:right"><img src="/img/image.gif" alt="" width="314" height="11" border="0" /></div>
    <div class="imghead" style="float:left"><a href="/"><img src="/img/mh_image.jpg" alt="" width="260" height="60" border="0" /></a><noscript><p class="noScriptHead">This page uses Javascript. Your browser either doesn't support Javascript or you have it turned off.<br />To see this page as it is meant to appear please use a Javascript enabled browser.</p></noscript></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would guess that one works and the other doesn't because of the "2". You have in there. Which is weird, I would check W3C valid id documentation.

Comment: I thought that as well, but the one with "2" actually work in both browsers.

Comment: Also, I would suggest changing your code to `$(".imghead img[src='/img/mh_image.jpg']")`, just so there's no room for quirks...

Comment: I know this is probably not the issue, but did you try clearing cache, shift-refresh, etc? I always get caught up on the small things...

Comment: Yep, it's definitely not a cache issue. I had also taken the same steps as NeXXeuS - validating, and adding single quotes around the src, but it's still MIA.

Comment: Could we see the HTML for your `<div>`?

Comment: I can't test this because I hate debugging JS in IE, but it could have to do with how the SRC tag is resolved. Some browsers rewrite HREF into the fullly qualified path (incl. domain name), and I bet the same applies to SRC on images. Try using the contains selector `~=` and see if it works.

Comment: FIXED: It wasn't "~" but a "*" that got it working. Thanks for the help guys -- Previous comment-- Added the html. Have also tried the full domain as well as ~, and * before the equals sign. This is insane.

Comment: I should also note that I do not get a script error in IE.

Comment: Technically, quotes are *mandatory* surrounding the value in a jquery attribute selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ I am not personally very good about using them, since it seems to be one of those "optional mandatory" things, but since you are using potentially dangerous characters (slashes), I would also try adding the quotes.

Comment: I think the quotes helped since previously adding a "*" did not fix the issue. I only wish IE had thrown an error so it would have been quicker to debug.

Comment: Did you try escaping the slashes in the selector too?  e.g.:
$(".imghead img[src='\\/img\\/mh_image\\.jpg']").each(function() {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a * before the `=` and it seems to be running fine now:

```
$(".imghead img[src*='/img/mh_image.jpg']").each(function() {
        $(".imghead").prepend('<a href="#"><img src="/img/image.png" border="0" id="anniversary" alt="" /></a>');
         });
```